# Bean to PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

I am wondering if there is an opposite tool like bean-loader ( http://code.google.com/p/bean-loader/ ). I just want to genereate a prepared statement out of a bean. Because I do not need a fully blown ORM framework but want to save the time for coding all the different jdbc prepared statement setters for all the different data types.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [POJava Persistence](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pojava/persistence/2.8.0).  You can find some example code [here](http://www.pojava.org/howto/dao.html) to see if it matches your needs.  Full disclosure... I wrote the thing, but I still think it's a good fit for what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for the link, I am not sure if this fits my needs. I do not want a too generic jdbc compatible framework. I choose a special database because of its special features (like insert on duplicate key, replace into instead of insert, etc.). And thats the problem to use special features you can not use gerneric ORM. At least not without ugly hacks :-)

Comment: POJava is generic in the sense that it boils the problem down to a String with bindings.  It doesn't try to support the intersection of features in common between databases.  Instead, it uses an underlying object called "BoundString" which encapsulates both a String and a set of bindings, separate from implementation.  If your specialized features map to an arbitrary language with bindings then it might yet fit your needs.

Comment: A cool, this is what I would need, sorry could not figure this out by a quick view on the the docs. I will check POJava - thanks!